# Safari 17.2 (macos) audio src not loading when set to object url

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

I have Safari 17, macos. I am trying to set the `src` of an `audio` tag like `<audio src="blob:...">`

```js
    // 'data' is set to a data url, e.g. data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzBAAA etc
    const audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    const spl = data.split(',');
    const binary = atob(spl[1]);
    const mime = spl[0].split(':')[0].split(';')[0];
    let ar = []; for (let i=0; i<binary.length; i++) { ar.push(binary.charCodeAt(i)); }
    blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(ar)],{type: mime});
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

In Firefox & Chromium-based browsers this all works fine. Safari gives me the word `Error` on the audio control, the error `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable.` on the console, and refuses to play.

I understand that browsers can just handle having the data url as the `src` but I would prefer the blob *reference* rather than a string *copy* in the src, as the contents can be quite large.

The audio tag is just `<audio controls>`; it adds the blob `src` attribute. I've also tried explitly adding the `type='audio/mp3'` or `type='audio/mpeg'` attributes as well, but these do not change the message or error. Safari just seems unable to play object urls.

Does anybody know what the definition of `not suitable` is in the errors context?

Comment: Typo: `spl[0].split(':')[0].split(';')[0];` You're splitting the string `data` at `;` here. Should be ` spl[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];` https://jsfiddle.net/a5jm7e9s/

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=232076#c30 talks about blobs requiring the correct blob.type (which is set) - doesn't help.

Comment: `spl[0].split(':')[0].split(';')[0]` gets the mime type, for correctly setting the blob type.  the bytes inside the base64 are gathered from `atob(spl[1])`.

Comment: `spl[0]` is `"data:audio/mp3;base64,"`,  `.split(':')[0]`  is `"data"`, `.split(';')[0];` is still `"data"`. You want the part **after** `":"`, so `spl[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];`,

Comment: @Kaiido gah! smh

Comment: *"smh"* as in you still don't get it? So to be extremely clear, at the line 5: column 36 of your code snippet, you should replace `0` with `1`, so as to get the proper section of the data URI header that points to the mime type, so the line should be     `const mime = spl[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];`, note how `.split(':')[0]` became `.split(':')[1]`.